# p:ajax event="sort" of p:dataTable does not process

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

For some strange reason I can't manage to process my data when I'm using `<p:ajax event="sort"` inside `<p:dataTable` , while it works just fine for `<p:ajax event="page"` and `<p:ajax event="filter"`

*I'm using myfaces 2.0.11 with primefaces 3.4 (tried with 4.0 snapshot)*

If I edit my cell input and do ***PAGINATE*** I ***do*** see the updated value of the cell in the listener method

If i edit my cell input and do ***SORT*** I ***do NOT*** see the updated value of the cell in the listener method, Any Idea why? I mean both p:ajax (sort/page) got the process="@form" so why its does not process? I inspected the network of the chrome dev tools and in both cases (sort/page) the relevant updated values are being sent to the server, but for some reason in the sort listener the values are not updated ,

b.t.w the only suspicious difference between page and sort ajax request is the following parameter that is present only in the sort request is:

`my_table_skipChildren:true` , what does it mean? skip from processing ?

I can grab the relevant ids+value from the request from the ExternalContext, but it will be last resort only

Here is a really simple example

**Session Scoped Bean code:**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class myBean {
    private List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        myList.add(new MyObject("1", "2"));
        myList.add(new MyObject("11", "22"));
        myList.add(new MyObject("111", "222"));

        myList.add(new MyObject("1a", "2a"));
        myList.add(new MyObject("11a", "22a"));
        myList.add(new MyObject("111a", "222a"));
   }

    public List<MyObject> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

    public void setMyList(List<MyObject> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }   
}
```

**MyObject code**

```
public class MyObject {

   private String one;
   private String two;

   public MyObject(String one, String two) {
      super();
      this.one = one;
      this.two = two;
   }

   public String getOne() {
      return one;
   }

   public void setOne(String one) {
      this.one = one;
   }

   public String getTwo() {
      return two;
   }

   public void setTwo(String two) {
       this.two = two;
   }
}
```

**XHTML :**

```
<p:dataTable id="my_table" value="#{myBean.myList}"
   var="deviceRow" widgetVar="myTable"
   paginator="true" rows="4" paginatorPosition="bottom"
   paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">

   <p:ajax process="@form" event="sort" listener="#{myBean.detectSortEvent}"></p:ajax>
   <p:ajax process="@form" event="page" listener="#{myBean.detectPageEvent}"></p:ajax>

   <p:column id="table_selection_column_one" sortBy="#{deviceRow.one}" filterBy="#{deviceRow.one}">

      <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Column One" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:inputText id="myRow_One" value="#{deviceRow.one}" />
   </p:column>

   <p:column id="table_selection_column_two" sortBy="#{deviceRow.two}" filterBy="#{deviceRow.two}">
      <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Column Two" /> 
      </f:facet>
      <h:inputText id="myRow_Two" value="#{deviceRow.two}" />
   </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

(I also asked it on primefaces forum but got no response)

---

Tried **Andy** workaround (adding `editable="true"` to table, but its no good

The scenario is as follows: change some value of an input text , than click on table column header to do sort

*Expectations*: Inside detectSortEvent listener I see the updated value inside the list

*Reality*: Same old value in the list

Regards,

Daniel.

Comment: Weird...When you say you do sort, you mean by clicking on the arrow icon on the column header ? If so, I was able to reproduce this with pf 3.5 but one workaround I found was to set `editable="true"` in `p:dataTable`. When I edited a value, sorted that column and did a `System.out.println` in `detectSortEvent` The new value was shown in the list.

Comment: Yes I mean changing the value of checkbox(for example) and than click the arrow icon on the column header, I tried adding the editable="true" , but its no good, Updated my question (in the bottom) thanks.

Comment: My apologies, you're right. Not sure where I screwed up but it works with `p:cellEditor`. To make sure we're on the same page here's the code I'm using to test http://pastebin.com/EARmJSZ6. Let me know what I'm doing wrong. I took out the one `p:ajax`, `paginatorTemplate` and added `detectSortEvent`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using `<p:cellEditor>` at all , instead I display `<h:inputText id="myRow_One" value="#{deviceRow.one}" />` in the column , so its always editable (I mean I can send its value to the server on page/filter events) , I have asked it on primefaces forum and opened and issue , but there is no clear answer on this yet... http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=32284

Comment: Oh yes I understand, I only wanted to show you a workaround. This issue is interesting.

Comment: Oh and Daniel, they have this rule on their forum where you have to put your signature a certain way. Maybe that's why they haven't replied. I only read the first three post so far. I can't find the out where it says that.

Comment: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1194 It's even in bold XD

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the workaround, unfortunately I need to use plain table without the celleditor

Comment: Not a problem, I'll keep digging. Hopefully you'll have an answer soon.